# HTML5 embed element types

Tags: html, embed

Where I can find the whole list of file extensions, supported by the `embed` tag? It seems I can't open `.docx` file, while `.pdf` and `.jpeg` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this tag will support any file type that client computer supports. You can't open Word documents because you do not have any software associated with this file type in your operating system. If you install Office than you will be able to open them and browser will know how to handle it. You can open Pdf because ex Chrome supports them already, and the same is with images.
Some file types can be supported by the browser externally, when there are no plug-ins or players. In this situation when user click on this kind of file it is downloaded locally and associated software opens it. If you have some plug-in installed than browser will use it to open file inside the window. It very much depends what kind of files you want to work with.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for this. It is implementation specific. It will vary both by the browser and by the plugins installed in the browser.